# GCE instance startup script error handling

Tags: google-compute-engine, startupscript

On GCE platform I have a Managed Instance Group for which a template is assigned.
The template has a startup script (bash) that pulls the latest code from a git repo and installs a few requirements.

Occasionally the startup script fails to update the code or fails to update the requirements.

In this case I would like to abort the startup.

What would be the correct way to go about this?

- How do I signal the error?
- Can I get the machine to restart or are there other options?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups